# I want to display the online user when they have logged on

Tags: php, authentication

I would like to display:
Logged in as:***_*__*_*___**

The code so far:

The login check,

```
<?php
include('config.php');

// username and password sent from form 
$myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myemail = stripslashes($myemail);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myemail = mysql_real_escape_string($myemail);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myemail' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['myemail'] = $myemail; 
header("Location: http://www.jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/login_success.php?            user=$myemail"); } 
else 
{ header("Location: http://www.jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/loginerror.php"); 
} 
?>
```

The login success page/first members page,

```
<? 
$email = $_GET['myemail']; 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['myemail'] = $email;  

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ 
} else { 
echo " 
<script language='javascript'> 
alert('Sorry, but you must login to view the members area!') 
</script> 
<script> 
window.location='http://jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/sign_in.php' 
</script> 
"; } 
?>

<html>
blah blah blah
</html>
```

The code used to display the users email,

```
Logged in as: <? echo "$email"; ?>
```

The log in side of things is perfect. Just displaying the users email is proving difficult. What have I done wrong/missed out?

Comment: Your comment "// To protect MySQL injection" is in a misleading place. `stripslashes` does **not** prevent SQL injection. It should be used when magic_quotes_gpc is on and you don't have permission to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to display values out from the session, you have to use `$_SESSION['email']`.

```
session_start(); // Or, if you have done it ahead, then omit this
echo "Logged in as:".$_SESSION['email'];
```

Comment: is this contained in `<? ?>`?

Comment: @blanksby, Not neccessarly but YES inside a PHP wrapper.

Comment: I have replaced `<? echo "$email"; ?>` with `<?php echo "Logged in as:".$_SESSION['email']; ?>` and still no joy?

Comment: Also ensure that the `session_start()` comes _before_ any other code, including `$email = $_GET['myemail'];`

Comment: @blanksby, Have to started the `session_start()` before you are trying to display it?

Answer (score 1):

Use Starx suggestion on the `$_SESSION` but you need to move your `session_start` as the first line of PHP on the page, above `$email = $_GET['myemail'];` (or `$email = $_SESSION['email']`)

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
?>
```

**ADDED**

To use the session variable, declare it like so (assuming you are using a method=post on form submittal):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
?>
```

This of course isn't safe for user input, it's presumed that you are sanatizing the user input prior to passing it from page to page and injecting it into your queries, this is just a simple example.

Comment: I now have `<?php 
session_start(); 
$email = $_GET['myemail']; 
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;  

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ 
} else { 
echo "<script language='javascript'> 
alert('Sorry, but you must login to view the members area!') 
</script> 
<script> 
window.location='http://jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/sign_in.php' 
</script> 
"; } 
?>` and `<?php echo "Logged in as:".$_SESSION['email']; ?>` but still nothing.

Comment: Did you store the email into the session variable?  You have to assign it when on page load/refresh: `$_SESSION['email'] = myemail@email.com` or however you are retrieving the email in the form, but it needs to be assigned to that variable - it's not automatically populated because you started a session

Comment: And ensure that on all your pages you have `session_start()` as the first line of code or it will break from page to page

Comment: What the code should be doing is pulling the email from the url. When the login is accepted, the next url is, http://www.mysite.com/login_success.php?user=$myemail. I was hoping to take the $myemail and assign it as a new variable on the new page. I'm probably going about this completely the wrong way..

Comment: Yes, using session you won't have to add a subquery to each page.  It's probably not a great idea to pass a user login name (especially an email address) in the URL because then anyone can read it and voila! your users are getting spam email because a hacker read your user's URL as well as the fact that then they don't have to login everytime.  I can then just enter the url: `yoursite.com/myemail@email.com` and have direct access to my account without actually logging in

Answer (score 0):

Login Script:

```php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = sha1($password);

if ($username&&$password) {
        require_once('../db/nstDBconnector.php');
        $qr = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
        $query = mysql_query($qr);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows!=0) {
            // check password against the password in the database
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $storedUsername = $row['username'];
                $storedPassword = $row['password'];
                $storedUserType = $row['user_type'];
                $storedUserFName = $row['full_name'];
                $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
            // check to see if username and password match
            if ($username==$storedUsername&&$password==$storedPassword) {
                ob_start();
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $storedUsername;
                $_SESSION['user_type'] = $storedUserType;
                $_SESSION['full_name'] = $storedUserFName;
                header ('Location: main.php?login=successful');
            } else {
                header ('Location: index.php?error=incorrectPassword');
            }
        } else {
            header ('Location: index.php?error=noUser');
        }
    } else {
        header ('Location: index.php?error=missingUserAndPass');

    }
```

The page you are taking them to after login:

```php
if ($_SESSION['username']) {
    $userLogged = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userType = $_SESSION['user_type'];
    $userFName = $_SESSION['full_name'];
} else {
    header ('Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?error=notLoggedIn');
}
```

Where you want to show user name on the page:

```html
Logged in as <?php echo $userFName; ?>.
```

or

```php
echo "Logged in as ", $userFName, ".";
```